# Passing php file to json fail to load data

Tags: php, json

I have tried to add a php file as the source of data for a jquery calendar that uses json as below:

```
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#eventCalendarHumanDate").eventCalendar({
        eventsjson: 'modules/events/json/event.humanDate.json.php',
        jsonDateFormat: 'human'  
            });
      });
   </script>
```

The php file works when i echo variables only but when i connected to the database and looped, it fails and i get the error "error getting json" But running my code separately i get no error from the php file itself.

```
    <?php
$hostname_app_conn = "localhost";
$database_app_conn = "xx";
$username_app_conn = "xx";
$password_app_conn = "";
$app_conn = mysql_pconnect($hostname_app_conn, $username_app_conn, $password_app_conn) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
mysql_select_db($database_app_conn, $app_conn );

$query_rs_content = "SELECT * FROM `mod_events_events` WHERE `active`=1 ORDER BY `Id` LIMIT 365";
$rs_content = mysql_query($query_rs_content, $app_conn) or die(mysql_error());
$totalRows_rs_content = mysql_num_rows($rs_content);

header('Content-type: text/json');

echo '[';
$separator = "";
$days = 16;

$i = 1;
echo $separator;
    while($row_rs_content = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_content))
    {

    echo '  { "date": "'.$row_rs_content['eventday'].'", "type": "'.$row_rs_content['type'].'", "title": "'.$row_rs_content['Title'].'", "description": "'.$row_rs_content['teasertext'].'", "url": "" },';
        }

    $separator = ",";

echo ']';
?>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You do realize php has a built in function for generating json arrays right?

Comment: http://www.php.net/json_encode

Comment: please enlighten me. am not that good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `json_encode()` function, something like this:

```
//more code above
$array = new array();
while($row_rs_content = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_content))
{
    $array[] = array(
        'date' => $row_rs_content['eventday'],
        'type' => $row_rs_content['type'],
        'title' => $row_rs_content['Title'],
        'description' => $row_rs_content['teasertext'],
        'url' => '',
    );
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
die();
```

Most likely you had some character not being escaped properly or something else that was causing it not to be a valid json array so Javascript is dying trying to parse it.

Comment: This worked as if i did nothing. I think i should get some tutorial. actually, i have been using PHP for a long time joining stuff here and there but i have not educated myself. what is your recommendation?

Comment: Recommendation for educating yourself?

Comment: Nope, some recommended tutorial or how did you get to this level yourself? am interested..

Comment: Practice, lots of practice and anytime I didn't know how to do something google search or stackoverflow search. Also if you can find open source projects download the code and see how others have solved similar problems.

Comment: just trying your code from above `$array = new array();`  can be deleted, i now try to use ajax `$post()` sending each current loaded month to db and fetch only loaded month events.... pfffff need to find out 1st how to start :)